# Azure DevOps custom rule - Assigned Bug to @me when state changes

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My goal is to change the **Assigned to** field automatically using my own role. The role should apply if the status of the item (Bug) changes from **Active** to **Resolved**. In this case the item should not be assigned to the creater account but to the account, which performs the status change.

I cannot find a variable **@Me**. Any experience?

[image]

A further attempt unfortunately remained without success.

[image]

Comment: You sure your attempt doesn't work?  You are only trying to move from Active to Resolved?  Not from another status?  And you reloaded the board of work items AFTER you created the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced this issue. The custom rule doesnot work as expected for some users. You can [report this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) to Microsoft development team. Hope they will look into this issue.

However, you use extension [WIT one click actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohitbagra.witoneclickactions) as workaround. I tested this extension it works perfectly.

After the extension is installed. Yon can configure a new rule for the Bug work item and add the triggers and actions. See below:

[image]

Action:

[image]